# Display loading image while post with ajax is NOT Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is a div which contains a GIF animation:

```
<div id="busy">
    <br />
    Loading... Please Wait...
    <br />
    <img src="Resources/Scripts/loader.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

and Here is a Function which contains AJAX POST Method:

```
    function Handler(datas, ele) {
        $('#busy').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "FileUploadHandler.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: datas,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function () {
                    ele.width = 100;
                    $('#busy').hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

as you can see I have used show and hide on that target div. But it is not working at all and I do not know where is the problem?

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: nothing will show and hide!!!

Comment: Hm. Did you load the jQuery library? Do you call the `Handler()` function? Are there any JavaScript errors in your browser console?

Comment: Yes I have add script reference to jQuery library. I have called Handler() and it is working fine. The only problem is that Show and hiding the Div is not working.

Comment: Is it possible to create a demonstration of your problem? I [can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/ko9s9nue/3/) it.

Comment: How do you initially hide the div?  What if you don't hide it once the request completes, is it being displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) method in order to show loading progress and on complete hide it. Only in this case, you guarantee that on success/failure animation will be hidden.

```
 function Handler(datas, ele) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "FileUploadHandler.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: datas,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend  : function() {
                  $("#busy").show();
            },
            success: function () {
               ele.width = 100;

            },
            complete: function() {
                $("#busy").hide();
            }

        });
    }
```

```js
function showHide(){
  if($('#busy').css("display") == "none"){
      $('#busy').show();
  } else {
    
       $('#busy').hide();
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="busy">
<img src="https://rec.redsara.es/registro/img/loading.gif"/>
</div>



<input type="button" value="click" onclick="showHide()" />
```

Comment: @showdev Yes. I was writing ))

Comment: Nothing :( I put show function in a try catch block to see what happens. If I change a label text in try block just before show function it will work and the only thing it is not working is SHOW function.

Comment: Try this code. It is probably a jQuery problem

Comment: BeforeSend is not neccessary at all.  Simply showing the div before calling the ajax method should work fine.